# How to synchronize line hight of treeview and listview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an unusual need to display a tree view and a column view side by side so I can visually show a hierarchy, while also displaying the details of each item in a column format.  To do this,  I have a TreeView on the left, with a ListView on the right, and a splitter in between.

My problem is, that no matter what value I put for the ItemHeight property of the treeview, it never lines up to the ListView.  17px is slightly too small and 18px is slightly too big.  Has anyone done this before?

**16px Line Height:**
[image]:

**17px Line Height:**
[image]:

**18px Line Height:**
[image]:

Answer (score 0):

Just verified - when you set exactly same font and same ItemHeight (you can set it to TreeView), then rows of TreeView and ListView will be 'synchronized'.

Here is sample screenshot for font `San Serif, 9.75pt` and `ItemHeight` equal to 16:

[image]

Consider also using controls like [DevExpress TreeList](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraTreeListTreeListtopic). That will save you some time.

---

Here is another scrrenshot, which shows controls with `Microsoft San Serif, 8.28pt` and `ItemHeight` equal to 13:

[image]

Comment: I'm sure this is what I have set, and it's still not working.  I'll have to post a screenshot from work tomorrow

Comment: Posted screenshots.  I just can't seem to reproduce your results

Comment: @Jeremy please post just two things for **both controls** - full font name - e.g. `Microsoft San Serif, 8.25pt` and ItemHeigth

Comment: I can confirm, both are set to Microsoft Sans Serif and 8.25pt (the default settings for both controls)

Comment: @Jeremy it's not enough to set same font. Also set ItemHeight of TreeView.

Comment: sorry, that's done as well.  THe screenshots above show what it looks like while trying an ItemHieght of 16,17 and 18px will both controls are set to Microsoft Sans Serif 8.28pt

Comment: @Jeremy sorry, screenshot above shows what you should have when both are same